# What is the meaning of "how" in ""Oh, how I hope this won't happen again for ten years"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What is the meaning of "how" in the following sentence?

> As she poured on the soap, he cried, "Oh, how I hope this won't happen
>   again for ten years!"

Does "how I hope this won't happen" mean "I hope this won't happen" or "I cannot hope that this will not happen"?  Does he believe that this will happen again?

Comment: In this usage, think of "how" as short for "how much", not as a question but as an exclamation of a large amount.  It is a similar use case to "You can't imagine **how much** I hate this!"  Your sentence is an expression of a lot of hope, in this case for "this" not happening again for ten years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [how](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/how)
>   How is sometimes used for emphasis:
>   *How nice to see you!*
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

In the example given in OP, *how* doesn't really mean anything. Instead, it is used to emphasize his hope. It sounds a little dramatic or theatrical to me.
The statement itself is not intended to suggest anything about his belief. He is emphatically wishing that it won't happen again.

Casually phrased, it would be something like

> I really hope this won't happen again for ten years!